# Cross-thread exception throwing

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an application that allows users to write their own code in a language of our own making that's somewhat like C++. We're getting problems, however, where sometimes our users will accidentally write an infinite loop into their script. Once the script gets into the infinite loop, the only way they can get out is to shut the application down and restart, potentially losing their work. I'd like to add some means where the user, when he realizes that his code is in an infinite loop, can hit a special key, like F10 or something, and the code will break out of the loop. But I'd like to do it without implementing a ton of checks within the script runtime. Optimally, I'd like to have a separate "debugger" thread that's mostly idle, but as one of its tasks it listens for that F10 key, and when it gets the F10 key, it will cause the script runtime thread to throw an exception, so that it will stop executing the script. So my question is, is there a way to have one thread cause another thread to throw an exception? My application is written in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible.  Detect the keystroke in a separate thread, a hidden window and WM_HOTKEY for example.  Call SuspendThread() to freeze the interpreter thread.  Now use GetThreadContext() to get the CPU registers of the interpreter thread.  Modify CONTEXT.Eip to the address of a function and call SetThreadContext().  Have that function call RaiseException() or throw a C++ exception.  ResumeThread() and boom.

Answer (score 2):

If the script is actually interpreted by your application then you can just tell the interpreter to stop executing whenever some user event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer - no.

If your application runs on Windows, maybe you can send a message from this "debugger" tread and have a message loop in the main one?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that solution is, to do a message sending implementation, I'd have to set up a "listener" as part of the script interpreter. Right now, the interpreter just executes the function. The message loop is implemented outside of the interpreter. If within the function there is an infinite loop, then to break out of that script, I'd have to check for a message in between execution of each instruction in the interpreter, i.e. while(more instructions){check F10, execute script instruction}. That seems like a lot of extra unneeded checks that can slow down the script execution. But if that's the only solution, then I guess that's what it has to be. I still think there's got to be a better way. Maybe the script interpreter needs to be run on a child thread, while the main thread continues its message loop, and will then kill the script interpreter thread when it gets an F10.

Comment: "The problem with that solution is, to do a message sending implementation, I'd have to set up a 'listener' as part of the script interpreter" sounds a lot like "I want this new functionality, but I don't want to change the code to get it."  Sorry, but I think you'll need to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is unsafe to terminate a thread, as it is probably using resources shared across the entire process.

It is less unsafe to terminate an entire process, but that's not going to help you.

A more safe way to deal with this would be to have the interpreter check for events on a regular basis and treat the stop event as a case to terminate (or at least spill out to a higher loop).

For windows, you could also queue an APC to that thread that calls `RaiseException(...)` or throws an exception, (although I would avoid the latter, since that crosses API boundaries), but that also implies that the thread will put itself into an alertable state. And I don't really recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you code it explicitly or not, you will need to check a "interrupt" variable in the message loop. If you implement this by a simple `volatile int`, you will have both a very simple test and very little overhead.